# Reverse labels without reversing the coordinates in circuitikz

Tags: labels, circuitikz, coordinates

How do I flip the label to the bottom without having to flip the coordinates?

```
\documentclass[preview, american, convert]{standalone}

\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw
    (0,0) to[C=\(C_f\)] ++(1,0);
\end{circuitikz}
```

[image]

How do I flip the label to the bottom without having to flip the coordinates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `l=<label>` option to specify the label, and then you can use `^` or `_` to chose the position.  Here is a comparrision of `l=`, `l^=`, and `l_=` syntax:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw (0,0) to[C, l ={\(C_f\)}] ++(1,0);
    \draw (2,0) to[C, l^={\(C_f\)}] ++(1,0);
    \draw (4,0) to[C, l_={\(C_f\)}] ++(1,0);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```